# when i call splash screen then this it check granted after get granted tru it call my aplication again and again

Tags: android

```
    this is my handler class to call a splash screen




    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

boolean granted = false;

                @Override
                public void run() {

                   /*if (granted == true) {
                        if (savePreferences.getPreferences_integer(getApplicationContext(), Constant.loginaccessTocken) == 1) {

    ## here is call my intent ##
                        } else {
                           ## here is call my intent ##
```

this code is calling again and again and i want to remove this it automaticall call splah creen and then login and the splah and the login
                            }
                            finish();

```
                    } else {
                        final Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
    }
            }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
        }


    help me out from this situation
```